# How to determine Sentinel Productnames for EarthEngine/AWS/GoogleStorage

Tags: sentinel-2, google-earth-engine

How would I know the granule name for sentinel data in Google Earth Engine? I tried to look up the granule name in the "index.csv.gz" (gs://gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/index.csv.gz) and "scihub" but cannot get the code running. Here are the field names in the index.csv.gz `GRANULE_ID,PRODUCT_ID,DATATAKE_IDENTIFIER,MGRS_TILE,SENSING_‌TIME,TOTAL_SIZE,CLOU‌​D_COVER,GEOMETRIC_QU‌​ALITY_FLAG,GENERATIO‌​N_TIME, NORTH_LAT,SO‌​UTH_LAT,WEST_LON,EAS‌​T_LON,BASE_URL`.

On the other hand this is the sample granule ID I got from scihub: `S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_EPA__20170512T230414_A002288_T50PQA_N02.‌​04`.

I am struggling how to determine sentinel ID (specifically Granule ID) in Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [Earth Engine public data catalog](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#index), Sentinel-2 data is stored in the "COPERNICUS/S2" image collection. The naming convention for the images is described on the [Sentinel-2: MultiSpectral Instrument (MSI), Level-1C](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/COPERNICUS%2FS2) dataset description page:

> Each Sentinel 2 product (zip archive) contains multiple granules. Each
>   granule becomes a separate Earth Engine asset. EE asset ids for
>   Sentinel 2 assets look like this:
>   COPERNICUS/S2/20151128T002653_20151128T102149_T56MNN. Here the first
>   numeric part represents the sensing date and time, the second numeric
>   part represents the product generation date and time, and the final
>   6-character string is a unique granule identifier indicating its UTM
>   grid reference (see MGRS).

A typical workflow for Sentinel-2 data analysis is to start with the  entire Sentinel-2 collection, and then apply spatial and temporal filters:

```js
// Define an object that refers to the Sentinel-2 collection.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

// Filter the Sentinel-2 collection by time and location.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-5.55, 35.96]);
var s2_filtered_1 = s2.filterDate('2017-05-01', '2017-06-01')
                      .filterBounds(roi);
print('Collection filtered by time and location', s2_filtered_1);
```

To obtain the Granule IDs, you can extract metadata from the images in the filtered collection:

```js
// Extract the Granule ID(s) from the metadata of images in the collection.
var granual_id_list = ee.Dictionary(
  s2_filtered_1.aggregate_histogram('GRANULE_ID')
).keys();
print('GRANULE_ID list', granual_id_list);
```

You can also filter collections by arbitrary metadata, which allows you easily access an image based on the product ID found on the Copernicus Open Access Hub:

```js
// Filter the Sentinel-2 collection by Product ID obtained from the
// Copernicus Open Access Hub.
var id = 'S2A_MSIL1C_20170512T093041_N0205_R136_T34TDN_20170512T093649';
var s2_filtered_2 = s2.filterMetadata('PRODUCT_ID', 'equals', id);
print('Collection filtered by product ID', s2_filtered_2);
```